# What is an "Eber rule?" (Ruler to measure type)

Tags: tools, typesetting

I heard someone mention a tool that was used for specifying type in the pre-computer days, called an "Eber rule."

What was it and how was it used?

Is it the same thing as a font ruler? And did I spell Eber correctly?

Answer (score 7):

Generally, manual type measurement is done via an **E Scale**. Sometimes referred to as a **Type Scale**.

[image]

These can be [purchased](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015ASPM4) at any art supply store.

They are customarily see through plastic. In fact one company making them is called C-Thru. You would place it on top of a printed piece and move the scale to line it up with an uppercase E on the printed sample. This would tell you what type size that E was, and subsequently the rest of the type.

---

I don't know that I've ever heard the term "Eber rule". But it's been a while since I've needed one. Maybe I'm forgetting. You may have also overheard someone using a brand name for a ruler. The same way everyone refers to tissue as "Kleenex".

**Haber Rule maybe.**
In the back of my mind, far in a deep, dark, corner, I kind of recall "**Haber Rule**". However, Haber was a brand name I believe. A [comment here at Before & After's web site](http://www.mcwade.com/DesignTalk/2012/06/are-inches-or-picas-better/) seems to confirm that name.

Comment: As a professional graphic designer since about 1978 till about 2002, I remember it as Haber too... I still have my 18" metal Haber Ruler : )

Answer (score 2):

I never heard of "Eber". What I encountered was called Typo Ruler, Typographic Gauge, Typometer.

It usually look something like this [image: Typo Ruler]

For specific type printhouses printed their own typo books when you could see what type is available, what glyphs they have and ornaments. From 5pt to 150pt I think.

In USA you also had pica-point-inch line rulers.

You also don't need to buy it. Ask your local printer or CTF if they could prepare one for you.

On a funny note. Maybe somebody was talking about "Ebert Rule" as a funny name for rule of a thumb?